# Feature selection on tiled map service using ArcGIS Javascript API 3.17

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

My feature class has around 80,000 point features. So I've used tiled map service and generated the cached tiles for fast rendering on client browser.  I'm using ArcGIS Javascript API 3.17. Now I want to add select features option on map. I feel that adding feature layer for selection option alone will slowdown the data rendering on client browser.

How can I implement feature selection in my application?

Answer (score 1):

You must combine the [Drawing](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/toolbar_draw.html) sample and the [Query](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/query_nomap.html) sample.
 With the Drawing sample you can draw one geometry on the map (for example a rectangle), and with this geometry execute a query to a mapserver.
After this, you can draw the few geometries retrieved from the query.